# Unable to find "Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\EnseigneNationale" entity identifier associated with the UnitOfWork

Tags: doctrine, unit-of-work, symfony5, persist

Client.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EnseigneNationale", inversedBy="clients")
 * ...
 */
private ?EnseigneNationale $enseigneNationale;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientBanque", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * ...
 */
private ?Collection $clientBanques;
```

My data comes from an old database, I have to create a command that corrects some data in the database.

```
if (Condition) {
        /** @var ClientBanque $clientBanque */
        $clientBanque = $clientBanques[0];
        $clientBanque->setAA($aa);
        $this->manager->persist($client);
    }
```

When I persist, I got the error saying that doctrine unable to find "EnseigneNationale", that it can be  nullable and I m not using it in my persist changes.

Somthing wrong with my code ?? Help Please

PHP : 7.4
Symfony : 5.3
Doctrine : 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was me !! Sorry for disturb, I was adding $manger->clear()  who breaks everything

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is basically you've detached your object from entity manager. The object was removed from the identity map and is no longer managed by this entity manager.

You can attach the object back by calling `$managedCopy = $em->merge($object);`

Pay attention to the fact that `merge` returns a new object.

> The state of the passed entity will be merged into a managed copy of this entity and this copy will subsequently be returned.